# RecyclerView adapter custom listener interface

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a custom listener that I want to implement in my main activity so that it gets notified when the RecyclerView item gets clicked.

However, I'm not sure where to put `setMyAdapterListener` in the adapter. Where would I put it?

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;

    private List<Data> data;

    private MyAdapterListener myAdapterListener;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Object> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public interface MyAdapterListener {
        void onContainerClick();
    }

    public void setMyAdapterListener(MyAdapterListener myAdapterListener) {
        this.myAdapterListener = myAdapterListener;
    }

    public class ViewHolderItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public LinearLayout container;

        public ImageView poster;

        public ViewHolderItem(View v) {
            super(v);

            container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.container);

            poster = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.poster);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

            if (id == R.id.container) {
                if (myAdapterListener != null) {
                    myAdapterListener.onContainerClick();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem(v2);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Data item = (Data) data.get(position);

        holder.poster.setImageDrawable(someDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the setMyAdapter() just pass the arguments you currently have in your setMyAdapterListener as part of your recyclerview's adapter contructor, see below:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Object> data, MyAdapterListener myAdapterListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.myAdapterListener = myAdapterListener;
    }
```

//On your activity you have to implement the methods of your interface.

Answer (score 0):

As @ScottS Said you dont need setMyAdapter() method, just pass the onclick listener Interface class as a argument to your adapter constructor then implement the interface methods in activity Class .. code is shown below.

```html
 public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Object> data) {
         this.context = context;
         this.data = data;
          this.myAdapterListener = myAdapterListener;
    }
    
    public interface MyAdapterListener {
    void onContainerClick(); // please provide 2 parameter that will help you more for manipulation like shown below
/// void onContainerClick(View view, int position); 
}

 }

public class ViewHolderItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public LinearLayout container;

    public ImageView poster;

    public ViewHolderItem(View v) {
        super(v);

        container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.container);

        poster = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.poster);

        container =setOnClickListener(this); /// this line must include
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        if (id == R.id.container) {
            if (myAdapterListener != null) {
                myAdapterListener.onContainerClick();
               // myAdapterListener.onContainerClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can handle the events in your Activity or wherever your RecyclerView is being used:

```html
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext() , data, new MyAdapter.MyAdapterListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onContainerClick(View v, int position) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "iconTextViewOnClick at position "+position);
                    }

                });
mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```